# How could I save emails from outlook IMAP client on local machine?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, backup, imap, email-client

Unfortunately, we have no access to our mail server anymore because of some reasons and we have no backup.

The clients used to connect via outlook IMAP. The emails are still in their mailboxes.
My question is How can I save these emails without access to the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This guide is for the current outlook (o365) version.

You need to create a PST file/outlook data file to store the emails. Normally created under the ribbon 'New Items' button, then More Items, Outlook Data file. Select the location, and password options if needed.

This will then create a new blank data file on your local disk, accessible on the left at the bottom of your folders.

Don't drag and drop as the default action is Move. Select the emails you wish to copy to the folder with the mouse, right click and go to Move, then 'Copy to folder'. Select or create a new folder within the outlook data file you created.

The emails will then be in the new outlook data file.